# Google Analytics Duplicate Transactions

Tags: google-analytics, transactions, duplicates, universal-analytics

I'm using Universal Analytics on my order confirmation page:

```
// Create the tracker
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');

// Fire off a pageview
ga('send', 'pageview');

// Include the ecommerce plugin
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

// Initialize the transaction
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
             id: '1234abc',     // Transaction ID*
    affiliation: 'Tech Shirts', // Store Name
        revenue: '52.19',       // Total
       shipping: '10',          // Shipping
            tax: '3.22'         // Tax
});

// Add a few items
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
          id: '1234abc',            // Transaction ID*
         sku: 'TSHIRT-12A',         // Product SKU
        name: 'Analytics Wizard',   // Product Name*
    category: 'Men\'s Shirts',      // Product Category
       price: '12.99',              // Price
    quantity: '1'                   // Quantity
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
          id: '1234abc',            // Transaction ID*
         sku: 'TSHIRT-36B',         // Product SKU
        name: 'Best Developer',     // Product Name*
    category: 'Women\'s Shirts',    // Product Category
       price: '12.99',              // Price
    quantity: '2'                   // Quantity
});

// Send off the transaction
ga('ecommerce:send');
```

For some reason the analytics team have decided to record the same transaction twice if the user refreshes the page.

It seems illogical to record the same transaction twice given that transaction ID is the same (it obviously represents the same transaction so why duplicate it?).

Is this expected behaviour as it is not documenated? Do the GA team really expect every user to have to write code to prevent duplications?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. This enables you to send negative transactions to cancel a purchase. You need to modify the page code to not include the e-commerce tracking on reload.

Comment: That sounds like a terrible design feature..why no just have a separate method to delete a transaction based on the idea? I find it ridiculous that I need to setup DB persistence to prevent duplicate transactions.

Comment: It's a fine design feature. GA e-commerce tracking is not a transaction-oriented database; it's just a logging and reporting engine. It's designed to give you an idea of what content contributes towards sales. You don't need to persist anything to a database to prevent duplicate transactions on page refresh. All you need is a bit of JavaScript. There's plenty of suggestions on how to detect page reload using JavaScript here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: By definition you now have to move from a stateless to stateful system. You could store the state in a cookie but what happens if the user bookmarks or emails the confirmation page and opens on another browser?

Comment: The only robust way to prevent duplicates is to persist the state into a DB.

Comment: As to how its a fine design feature...I think thats debatable. The fact its not even documentated means that most users wont even realise this. In any case, I cant imagine anyone who would prefer this rather than just have an add and delete method. I can't even reverse the transactions properly as the reversed transactions are recorded on a different date and only net if you include both dates.

Comment: You can switch to Enhanced Ecommerce to have a dedicated feature to import refund data (however afaik this will still recored multiple transactions send with the same id). In any case SO is not the place to appeal implementation decisions made by Google.

Comment: Some bit of documentation can be found here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en-GB, regarding transaction reversal/refund.

Answer (score 1):

We actually wrote a little bit of javascript which cookies the transaction ID and prevents it being sent to Google twice. Avoids the need to start writing server side code or modifying the code in your chosen ecommerce platform.

http://www.inventpartners.com/eliminate-duplicate-transactions-in-google-analytics

Essentially, just include the bit of JS and then wrap a conditional around your GA transaction tracking code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkIsSent(ref) {
    var cookiename = 'gaSaleSent_' + ref;

    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(cookiename + '=') != -1){
            return true;
        }
    }

    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (90*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cookiename + '=1; ' + expires;

    return false;
}

if(!checkIsSent('YOUR CART ID HERE')){
      PASTE YOUR GOOGLE TRANSACTION TRACKING CODE HERE
}
</script>
```

Comment: You link is broken so your code is virtually useless.

Comment: And this doesn't seem to be the best solution anyway. Provided that anyone can access that confirmation page from a different browser thus the cookie will not be present.